# Issue with GWT XML Parser using cast to Element

Tags: java, xml, gwt, xml-parsing

I am using GWT XML Parser to parse an xml file on my app. I am following this example: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html

But I get a error during class cast. Here is the stack trace:

```
ERROR: Failed to create an instance of 'xds.metadata.editor.client.editor.DocumentModelEditorView' via deferred binding 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.xml.client.impl.ElementImpl cannot be cast to com.google.gwt.user.client.Element
```

And here are my sources:

```
Document dom= XMLParser.parse(PreParse.getInstance()
                .doPreParse(AppResources.INSTANCE.codes().getText()));

List<CodedTerm> classCodes=new ArrayList<CodedTerm>();

NodeList nodes= dom.getElementsByTagName("CodeType");

if (predefinedCodes.equals(PredefinedCodes.CLASS_CODES)){
    if (classCodes.size()==0) {
        int index = 0;
        // it is during the next line I get my error
        while (!((Element) nodes.item(index)).getAttribute("name").equals("classCode")) {
            index++;
        }
        // ....
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why I get this classCastException whereas they do exactly the same thing in gwt-project sample code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it.** I was importing the wrong Element class.

Be carefull to `import com.google.gwt.xml.client.Element;` and not something else.